# Compile time error when adding an Integer to a generic ArrayList of String

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, collections

I know this question has been asked multiple times before but I'm looking for an answer based on type erasure.

Why does the compiler give an error on adding `Integer` to `ArrayList<String>`? I want to understand this by type erasure and byte code of `add` method in `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with type erasure or byte code. The compiler gives you this error before it erases the generic type parameters and generates the byte code.

When adding an `Integer` to an `ArrayList<String>`, the compiler simply gives you an error because an `Integer` is not a sub-class of `String`.

Generics simply add a layer of type safety in compile time. If you would use raw `ArrayList` instead of `ArrayList<String>`, you would be able to add both `String`s and `Integer`s to your `ArrayList`. However, the generated byte code is the same regardless of whether you used `ArrayList` or `ArrayList<String>`.

Comment: What I have read is erasure refers to replacing Object with generic Type so both of them are subclasses of Object

Comment: but you declare your ArrayList with String, now the compiler know it, if the compiler wouldn't give you an error, then it would be crash at runtime with an ClasscastExcpetion

Comment: @user2653926 But erasure happens only if the code passes compilation. If it fails to pass compilation, no byte code is generated, and no erasure takes place.

Answer (score 4):

Even though type erasure means that at *execution* time the VM can't distinguish between an `ArrayList<String>` and an `ArrayList<Integer>` (they're both just instances of `ArrayList`) the compiler *does* know about the type argument, and knows what's safe.

So if you have:

```
ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
integers.add("foo");
```

then the compile-time type of `integers` is `ArrayList<Integer>`, and any operations performed on `integers` will be checked with that in mind. The only `add` calls in [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) are

```
add(E e)
add(int index, E e)
```

Now there's no conversion from `String` to `Integer`, so neither of those overloads is applicable for the call `integers.add("foo")`, hence the compile-time error.

Basically, generics provide two things:

- Compile-time safety to avoid this sort of broken code; if you've said that a list should only contain `Integer` references, the compiler won't let you add a `String` reference to it
- Simplicity in terms of casts - when a method of a class with a type parameter `T` returns a value of type `T` and the compiler knows what that `T` is, it can insert an appropriate cast from the erased type (often `Object`) to the type argument. That's how:

  ```
  List<Integer> integers = getListFromSomewhere();
  Integer x = integers.get(0);
  ```

  works - the compiler adds a cast in the calling code. (That cast is still checked at execution time.)

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with a small example (note this uses [raw types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html); and they are evil),

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("Hello");
    List<Integer> al = new ArrayList(strings);
    for (Integer v : al) {
        System.out.println(v);
    }
}
```

It compiles. If we run it we get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at com.stackoverflow.Example.main(Example.java:11)
```

Because `String` is not `Integer`. We can examine the bytecode with `javap -v`

```
    35: invokeinterface #37,  1           // InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.next:()Ljava/lang/Object;
    40: checkcast     #43                 // class java/lang/Integer
    43: astore_3
    44: getstatic     #45                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
```

And see that the cast fails on the line numbered 40. Generic types are for compile time type checking, at run-time (almost) everything is an `Object`.